# WP8, null value in LoopingSelector DataSource

Tags: windows-phone-8, datepicker, datasource, toolkit, loopingselector

I am using Windows Phone Toolkit nuget package (http://phone.codeplex.com/). I want to create a LoopingSelector in my WP8 application, where I can select day dates, but I don't want the LoopingSelector to show days before today in it's selection.

My control looks like this:

http://s2.postimg.org/6bgnxefnt/image.png

This is perfectly working until I select the first element of the source (today Dec 04), then my application becomes unresponsive (I can press buttons, effect are shown, but the event handlers won't execute). I guess this is an infinite loop or deadlock, but it's not in my own code (I debugged it).

The definition of the LoopingSelector's data source:

```
public class NextDatesDataSource : LoopingDataSource<NextDateModel>
{
    public NextDatesDataSource() : base(NextDateModel.Create(DateTime.Today)) { }
    protected override NextDateModel GetNext(NextDateModel relativeTo)
    {
        if (relativeTo.Date == DateTime.Today + TimeSpan.FromDays(10))
            return null;
        return NextDateModel.Create(relativeTo.Date + TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
    }
    protected override NextDateModel GetPrevious(NextDateModel relativeTo)
    {
        //if i comment the next two lines, then everything works perfect
        if (relativeTo.Date == DateTime.Today)
            return null;
        return NextDateModel.Create(relativeTo.Date - TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
    }
}
```

LoopingDataSource:

```
public abstract class LoopingDataSource<T> : ILoopingSelectorDataSource
{
    protected LoopingDataSource() { selectedItem = default(T); }
    protected LoopingDataSource(T initialSelection) { selectedItem = initialSelection; }

    protected abstract T GetNext(T relativeTo);
    protected abstract T GetPrevious(T relativeTo);

    public object GetNext(object relativeTo)
    {
        if (relativeTo == null) return null;
        return GetNext((T)relativeTo);
    }

    public object GetPrevious(object relativeTo)
    {
        if (relativeTo == null) return null;
        return GetPrevious((T)relativeTo);
    }

    private T selectedItem;
    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            object oldVal = selectedItem;
            selectedItem = (T)value;
            if (SelectionChanged != null)
                SelectionChanged(this, new SelectionChangedEventArgs(new object[] { oldVal }, new object[] { value }));
        }
    }
    public T Selected
    {
        get { return (T)SelectedItem; }
        set { SelectedItem = value; }
    }

    public event EventHandler<SelectionChangedEventArgs> SelectionChanged;
}
```

The definition of the control element:

```
   <p:LoopingSelector
            x:Name="DaySelector"
            Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
            ItemSize="230,110"
            ItemMargin="6" Margin="10,5,5,5">
        <p:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" FontSize="28" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Body}" FontSize="42" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </p:LoopingSelector.ItemTemplate>
    </p:LoopingSelector>
```

I do this in the constructor:

```
        DaySelector.DataSource = new NextDatesDataSource();
```

Thank you very much!